# How to refresh ag-grid frequently with React?

Tags: reactjs, updates, ag-grid

I have an ag-grid instance, which have to be updated continuously, every few seconds, with fresh data by calling a service.
I want the grid to update only the cells with changed data.

Is there any way to achieve this using React?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you bind the grid data correctly, and don't alter the `rowBuffer`, or otherwise force the grid to render all its data to the DOM (thereby turning off virtualization), you should be fine.

the grid will test for changes in the data and only render what was updated (see the [docs on change-detection](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-change-detection/)).

if you still find you need some boost (like when you have real large datasets) you can try [batch-transactions](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/#batch-transactions).

all of the above is correct regardless of framework; these are core features of ag-grid.